# JavaScript - Creating a pause button in Space Invaders clone

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am creating a JavaScript/HTML program similar to Space Invaders where the ships come down from the top of the screen. I have a pause/resume and a restart button on top of my canvas but I am unsure if I am coding the buttons correctly as I am fairly new to JavaScript/HTML

Here is the HTML code for the Pause button:

```
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:700; left:25" value="Pause" onclick="pauseGame()"/>
```

Here is the function that is supposed to pause/resume the game (Not totally sure that the logic here is correct but I think it is):

```
function pauseGame() {

    if (gGamePaused === false) {
        game = clearTimeout(game);
        gGamePaused = true;
    } else if (gGamePaused === true) {
        game = setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000 / 30);
        gGamePaused = false;
    }

}
```

Am I doing this correctly? If so why is it not working?

Comment: This depends on how the _function_ `gameLoop` works and if there are any other _timeouts_ outside of `gameLoop` which won't be caught by the pause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
 function pauseGame() {
      if (!gamePaused) {
        game = clearTimeout(game);
        gamePaused = true;
      } else if (gamePaused) {
        game = setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000 / 30);
        gamePaused = false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: hmm..still the same issue. Clicking the button does nothing

Comment: make sure the other parts of your program are working correctly

Comment: The second `if` in this is not helpful because `!gamePaused; // false` means `gamePaused` is _truthy_.